# Purpose of WAN bridge interface

Tags: networking, bridge

Can I safely remove the second interface:

[image: WAN setup page]

Comment: Backup config to a file, try to remove. If something break, restore config. // Probably, this is some triple-play service like iptv.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I tried it, and I could no longer access the WAN, or even the router's configuration.

Comment: If its a standalone modem its briding the PPPoE WAN into the regular LAN, you want it.